# Time bucket in power bi

Tags: powerbi

[Time bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW6Gn.png)

column dax query:

```
Column = if(Table1[TransactionDate].[Date]=Table1[COBProcessDate].[Date], 
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
     HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate] )
    + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate]) / 60
    >= 6
    && HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate] )
        + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate] ) / 60
        < 8.5, "6:00 a.m. - 8:30 a.m.",
HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate])
    + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate]) / 60
    >= 8.5
    && HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate])
        + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate]) / 60
        < 9.5, "8:30 a.m. - 9:30 a.m",
HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate].[Date] )
    + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate]) / 60
    >= 9.5
    && HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate])
        + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate] ) / 60
        < 12, "9:30 a.m. to noon",
HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate] )
    + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate] ) / 60
    >= 12
    && HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate])
        + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate]) / 60
        < 15.5, "noon to 3:30 p.m.",
HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate].[Date] )
    + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate] ) / 60
    >= 15.5
    && HOUR ( Table1[COBProcessDate] )
        + MINUTE ( Table1[COBProcessDate] ) / 60
        < 18, "3:30 p.m. to 6:00 p.m.",
"6:00 p.m. - 6:00 a.m."),"Next Day")
```

I am not able to arrange time in correct series . like 6:30a.m-8:30a.m then 8:30a.m to 9:30a.m then noon to 6:30p.m then 6:30pm to 11:59 pm then next day.
screen shot is attached. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

by default the column values are alphabetically ordered, if you want or have to change this, you have to complete the following steps:

**Create another calculated column "column index"**
The column values will be used to order the column values of your 1st column.
The result will look something like this

```
... | column | column index
... | 6:00 a.m. - 8:30 a.m. | 1
... | 8:30 a.m. - 9:30 a.m. | 2
...
```

You can use the exact same DAX formula, but instead returning a string you will return a numeric value that represents the sort index

**Sort "Column" by "Sort Column"**
In the "Data-View" mark the column you want to order, switch to the "Modeling" ribbon and select "Sort by Column" - select the column that contains the numeric values.

**Hide the index column**
To avoid clutter in the Fields pane I always hide my index columns.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for

Regards
Tom